# Front end profiling

Tags: javascript, profiling, frontend

I am trying to help an open source project determine the cause of a front end slowdown.

I am seeing long load times on my end, a full page load takes 10-15 seconds, button clicks can take up to 30 seconds to respond, etc.

Service is running on my local network.

The load on the server is quite low (0.1) so I'm almost positive the issue is with rendering, DOM processing, and whatever other code is running.

curl also shows an extremely fast response, so I know the issue is with the front end.

They cannot reproduce on their end, but I can consistently reproduce on my end.

What else should be profiled besides javascript? What tools should I look into?

OS is Debian 8, browsers are firefox and chromium.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have the time - this two free and short courses will give you all the background and tooling you need:
https://www.udacity.com/course/browser-rendering-optimization--ud860
https://www.udacity.com/course/website-performance-optimization--ud884

Comment: Those look awesome. I'll start with that and go from there, thanks!

Comment: Hmmm...the second one requires you to debug with your smartphone attached to your dev machine. Seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to profile mobile performance, you use chrome on dev machine as the tool, but run the app on a mobile device.

Comment: No mobile performance profiling needed, just standard x86 desktops and laptops.

Comment: As the tutorial uses Chrome dev tools to debug, just skip the connecting mobile device.